# What's the proper way to call a destructor when you have a two-dimensional array (in C++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, destructor

This is my constructor:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int columns)
{
  elements = new int*[rows];
  for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
  {
    elements[x] = new int[columns];
  }
}
```

And this is my destructor:

```
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    delete elements;
}
```

I have changed the destructor to say "delete [] elements", "delete * elements", "delete elements*", and all sorts of combinations and every combination freezes up the program.  I have also tried "delete this" but that also freezes up the program.  I would try "free()" but I heard that's bad programming practice and it doesn't actually free the memory.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using a jagged array is no better than using a 2D `std::vector`. If that's what you want, use the vector and forget about this nonsense. If not, use a 1D array (such as a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` or `std::vector<int>`) wrapped in the `Matrix` class and also forget about this nonsense.

Comment: Try storing the dimensions of the `Matrix` and then use `for (int x=0; x<rows; x++){delete[] elements[x];} delete[] elements;`

Comment: Actually, I guess you could dereference your `elements` pointer and get the size of the array, thus eliminating the need to store the number of rows.

Comment: @chrisb2244, You'd get a pointer back, which doesn't contain the size.

Comment: @chris yeah - my bad. You'll only get the start of the array, not it's endpoint, so can't check for size, right?

Comment: You need to do one delete for each new.

Comment: @chrisb2244, Yup. All the more reason to have something that knows its size.

Comment: On a side note, it's the <pre> tags that were messing with your `<` sign. I removed them and reindented (you can use Ctrl-k to automatically indent code by 4 spaces, and format it as code. This won't affect previous indentation choices, like multiple tabs etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives me no leaks with `valgrind --leak-check=yes`

**Edit**: Added a copy-constructor to allow the `Matrix myMat2 = myMat;` style calls.
You should probably by this point be looking for a `swap` style function, and a copy-assignment operator. And so on, and so on...

```
#include <iostream>

class Matrix
{
    int** elements;
    int rows_;

    public:
    Matrix(int, int);
    ~Matrix();
    Matrix(const Matrix&);
};

Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int columns)
{
    std::cout<< "Matrix constructor called" << std::endl;
    rows_ = rows;
    elements = new int*[rows];
    for (int x=0; x<rows; x++)
    {
        elements[x] = new int[columns];
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for (int x=0; x<rows_; x++)
    {
        delete[] elements[x];
    }
    delete[] elements;
    std::cout<< "Matrix destructor finished" << std::endl;
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &rhs)
{
    std::cout<< "Called copy-constructor" << std::endl;
    rows_ = rhs.rows_;
    columns_ = rhs.columns_;
    elements = new int*[rows_];
    for (int x=0; x<rows_; x++)
    {
        elements[x] = new int[columns_];
        *(elements[x]) = *(rhs.elements[x]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Matrix myMat(5, 3);
    Matrix myMat2 = myMat;
    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
user:~/C++Examples$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./DestructorTest
==9268== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9268== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9268== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9268== Command: ./DestructorTest
==9268== 
Matrix constructor called
Called copy-constructor
Matrix destructor finished
Matrix destructor finished
==9268== 
==9268== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9268==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9268==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 12 frees, 200 bytes allocated
==9268== 
==9268== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9268== 
==9268== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9268== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Until you do `Matrix myMat2 = myMat;` :) (Not so much a leak as a double free in that case)

Comment: Just shamelessly pointing out how much more annoying it is to get this working and be confident that it is by doing things manually.

Comment: Oh, sure. `std::vector` all the way for me... Reinventing the wheel is fun, but not always a good plan, after all

Answer (score 0):

You should follow @chris' s advice. But if you want to know how to do it anyway:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    delete[] elements[i];
}

delete[] elements;
```